# Right triangle annotations on vectors

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing some force diagrams, and would really like the ability to draw a small right triangle on a line, like in the snapshot below.

Right now I'm drawing my force vectors like so:

```
\draw[force,->] (O) -- (C) 
    node[below] {$F_1 = \SI{850}{\newton}$};
```

I tried to create another node `node[midway] (midPoint) {}`, then `\draw (midPoint) -- ++(0,-3mm) -- ++(4mm,0)` however, there is some ugly gap between the vector and this tiny triangle.

Is there a library that I don't know about to help create annotations like these? Or perhaps more idiomatic tikz way of doing this?

[image: Right triangle on a line]

Thanks for your time!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

EDIT:
So I repurposed a tangentially related answer ([Triangle as constraints in structural engineering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118684/triangle-as-constraints-in-structural-engineering)) to some extent:

```
RightAngle/.style=
{
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.5 with {
        \draw[-, thin] (0,0) -- (0,-3mm) 
            node[midway, left] {\tiny 3};
        \draw[-,thin] (0,-3mm) -- (4mm, 0) 
            node[midway, below] {\tiny 4};
        }
    },
    postaction=decorate
}

\draw[force,->, RightAngle] (O) -- (C) 
    node[below right] {$F_1 = \SI{850}{\newton}$};
```

Which gets me almost there!  However I'm still missing something to do with the new local coordinate system.  How do I make that 3 leg come straight down (relative to the standard coordinate system)?

[image: Skewed triangle]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 3):

WIth `tikz` here is one way to do it: select the start point and end point on the vector itself:

```
\coordinate (Start Point) at ($(O)!0.3!(C)$);
\coordinate (End Point)   at ($(O)!0.5!(C)$);
```

In the above the `(Start Point)` is `0.3` along the length, and the `(End Point)` is at `0.5` along the path, and use `|-` to connect them which draws a vertical line followed by a horizontal line:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,4);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,-2);
    
    \draw[ultra thick, red, -latex] (O) -- (B) node[above] {$F_1 = \SI{950}{\newton}$};
    \coordinate (Start Point) at ($(O)!0.3!(B)$);
    \coordinate (End Point)   at ($(O)!0.5!(B)$);
    \draw [red] (Start Point) |- (End Point);
    
    \draw[ultra thick, blue, -latex] (O) -- (C) node[below] {$F_1 = \SI{850}{\newton}$};
    \coordinate (Start Point) at ($(O)!0.3!(C)$);
    \coordinate (End Point)   at ($(O)!0.5!(C)$);
    \draw [blue] (Start Point) |- (End Point);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The point `C` should be `(4,-3)` to make it have a consistent slope as described by the slope triangle. In addition, `End Point` must be `$(O)!0.8!(C)$`.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer: Thanks, but it is not clear to me that that is the requirement. The 3-4-5 triangle won't fit many vectors so the ability to draw that is rather limited.  I went with a general purpose method which will draw a right triangle on any vector..

Answer (score 0):

Just for typing exercise with PSTricks.

### Option 1

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset
{
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
    shortput=nab,
    linewidth=2pt,
    linecap=1,
}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,-4)
    \pstGeonode
        {A}
        (4,-3){B}   
        ([nodesep=1]{B}A){A'}
        ([offset=-30pt]A'){C}
        ([nodesep=40pt]C){B'}
    \ncline[linestyle=none]{A'}{B'}^{5}
    \ncline[linecolor=gray]{A'}{C}_{3}
    \ncline[linecolor=gray]{C}{B'}_{4}
    \ncline{->}{A}{B}
    \uput[-90](B){$F_1=\SI{850}{\newton}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Option 2

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset
{
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
    shortput=nab,
    linewidth=2pt,
    linecap=1,
}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,-4)
    \pstGeonode{A}(4,-3){B}([nodesep=1]{B}A){A'}([nodesep=50pt]{B}A'){B'}(A'|B'){C}
    \ncline[linestyle=none]{A'}{B'}^{5}
    \ncline[linecolor=gray]{A'}{C}_{3}
    \ncline[linecolor=gray]{C}{B'}_{4}
    \ncline{->}{A}{B}
    \uput[-90](B){$F_1=\SI{850}{\newton}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another PSTricks solution. Run with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[shortput=nab,arrowscale=1.5](5,-4)
\pnodes(0,0){A}(4,-3){B}   
\pcline[linewidth=1.5pt,arrows=->](A)(B)
\psLNode(A)(B){0.15}{C} \psLNode(A)(B){0.4}{D}
\pcline[linewidth=0.5pt](C)(C|D)_3 
\pcline[linewidth=0.5pt](C|D)(D)_4
\pcline[linestyle=none](C)(D)^5
\uput[-90](B){$F_1=850\,\textrm{N}$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]