# Simple beam deflection tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm beginner user of Tikz, so can somebody help me to draw this? I would be very thankful.
[image]

[image]

Comment: For this I would certainly go for the library tikz-mec: you can find an example in my answer to [Triangle as constraints in structural engineering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118693/13304)

Comment: In addition to the suggestion made by @ClaudioFiandrino , this is very similar to a question I recently answered [How to plot a figure like the attached?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237363/22413)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP did not put any effort in this question in the past 24 months, and probably will never do. Besides, the image is not available anymore.